# How to join different steps from same table in PowerQuery M - PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

My objective is to map, merge or join one column (the "Percent" column) in a step to another step of the PowerQuery M script using another identical column on both steps as key.

```
let
    Fonte = PostgreSQL.Database("localhost", "Database"),
    public_places = Fonte{[Schema="public",Item="public_places"]}[Data],
    #"Group1" = Table.Group(public_places, {"id", "place_name", "date"}, {{"Percent", each List.Average([Present_bool]), type nullable number}}),
    Today = Table.SelectRows(Group1, each Date.IsInCurrentDay([date])),
    #"Yesterday" = Table.SelectRows(Group1, each Date.IsInPreviousDay([date])),
    #"Rename" = Table.RenameColumns(Yesterday,{{"Percent", "PercentBefore"}}),
    CombinedTables = Table.NestedJoin(???) or Table.Join(???)
in
    CombinedTables
```

The idea is to get the "Percent" from the day before in the last table.
I don't believe I've been getting the arguments right in the last line, so I'll open to suggestion how to execute this Join. I'm not sure if that's possible at all or if I'm just getting the formula/arguments in the last line wrong. Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to lay data for prior day next to current day? IF so, you can just add a column made up of prior date = Date.AddDays([currentdatecolumn],-1) and then merge the table on top of itself matching date to prior date. Expand and there you have it

Comment: Save the common query, disable loading on it, and reference it in two new queries.  Then the UI can guide you through the transformation.  Once you see the correct M you can then collapse it into a single query if you like.

Comment: @horseyride no, i'm trying to get the percent of the prior day on the same table as the percent of the present day.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft are you suggesting to separate "Yesterday" into a different query? I would like not to create a separate query/table to hang in the process.

Comment: Just do that to answer your own question.  But a separate query won't necessarily be slower.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft It does work, but it creates a second table that won't be used anymore and can't be deleted because it's referenced somewhere else. Doesn't look optimal.

Comment: Disable loading on the table you don't need, and it won't load into your Dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for

[image]

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"date", type date}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "PriorDate", each Date.AddDays([date],-1),type date),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom", {"PriorDate", "type"}, #"Added Custom", {"date", "type"}, "Added Custom", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Added Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Added Custom", {"amount"}, {"Prior.amount"})
in  #"Expanded Added Custom"
```

It finds the amount for the prior date, for same type by merging the table on top of itself. You can then add a calculation based on the two columns if you want.  You could preface this with something like this to start off with fewer rows

```
= Table.SelectRows(Group1, each Date.IsInCurrentDay([date]) or Date.IsInPreviousDay([date]))
```